# Setting kAudioSessionMode in Apple's SpeakHere example causes big drop in volume. Any workarounds?

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

I've been having a problem with audio being too low in my own app any time I use the VoiceChat mode, so as an idiot-check I downloaded Apple's sample code for Audio Unit programming (SpeakHere) and added VoiceChat mode to that app. As it turns out, the problem happens there, too: running in that mode causes everything to be around 20% of the desired volume.

I added this code on line 267 of SpeakHereController.mm, right after the PlayAndRecord category is set:

```
    // set mode -- this results in audio being too soft
    UInt32 mode = kAudioSessionMode_VoiceChat;

    error = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_Mode, sizeof(mode), &mode);
    if (error) printf("couldn't set audio session mode!");
```

I'm using VoiceChat mode with RemoteIO in order to get echo cancellation for speakerphone usage; VoiceProcessingIO works (sort of), but performance on older iPhones (3GS) is so bad it's unusable -- that's why I'm using RemoteIO instead. I have confirmed that the speaker route is correct. I've even tried setting Measurement mode and manually increasing the gain -- I can't detect any improvement.

Any suggestions on preventing the big volume drop-off when using AudioSession modes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the /current/ audio route is used when the VoiceChat mode is set to determine the best settings for gain, echo cancellation, etc. Which means that if you're going to set a particular route, you need to do it before you set the mode -- not after.

Doing it in this order fixed the volume problem for me:

- set PlayAndRecord
- set route to speaker
- set the mode
- use VoiceProcessingIO in my audio units
- keep the hardware sample rate low (8k) to maintain good performance on older devices like the 3GS

Comment: I've got big volume drop-off from Apple's SpeakHere sample, too. To increasing volume in this sample, what shall I do?

Comment: can you elaborate what version of iOS you used and iphone model?

Comment: @user657429 It was iOS 6, using a variety of devices (iPhone 5, iPod touch, iPhone 3GS).

Comment: At last I found someone having the same problem as I do. Unfortunately this doesn't solve it for me.